# FTP get output redirect to a text file

Tags: ftp, io-redirection

I am running this shell script to get a file from FTP server.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
HOST='mininet-vm'
USER='mininet'
PASSWD='mininet'
FILE='index.html'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
ls
pwd
get $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

The output of `ls` and `pwd` is redirected to the file but the output of `get` is not redirected. I want this to be saved in the file, too.

Output of `get` command:

```
local: index.html remote: index.html
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 'mininet/index.html' (104857600 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
104857600 bytes received in 0.69 secs (148902.1 kB/s)
```

Please help me figure out the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `ftp` implementations inhibit some output, if the output or input is redirected.

You can force the output back using `-v` switch (verbose).

```
ftp -v -n $HOST > /tmp/ftp.worked
```