# Connect to a remote postgresql server using ftp

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I exported a database to a folder in a local ftp server (using `pg_dump`) in order to save some space on my computer. Now I want to connect to the generated `db.sql` file but without importing it again.
In PgAdmin I've created a new database, opened the `psql` tool and executed `\i /path/todb/db.sql`, which imports the database into my computer. However, I just need a remote connection over ftp.

I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: If you this solution works for your situation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938753/13808319 then you can pipe the output into psql.

Comment: Would this also work with sftp? I'm sorry I'm pretty new to database connections. Could you provide me of an example of the complete syntax?